# Get a variable work outside function in python

Tags: python, excel, variables

So im trying this:

I want an app to search specific extention on various folders, and then write all that in an excel
my problem is how can i take the last result of **x** to reuse it in the new function call? that way would not start from 1 or 0 again, and would continue to the next cell in the excel.

Thanks, sorry for english but isnt my main language ;)

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('videogames.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Videogames")

cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'center_across': True, 'font_size': 12})
cell_format2 = workbook.add_format({'font_size': 12})
worksheet.write(0, 0, "Game", cell_format)
worksheet.write(0, 1, "Console", cell_format)

def folder_check (folder, exten, console, width, x):
    for rom in os.listdir(folder):
        if rom.endswith(exten):
            if width > len(rom):
                width = width
            else:    
                width = len(rom)

            worksheet.set_column(x, 0, width)
            worksheet.set_column(x, 1, width)
            worksheet.write(x, 0, str(os.path.splitext(rom)[0]), cell_format2)
            worksheet.write(x, 1, str(console), cell_format2)
            x += 1

folder_check("E:\Games\Roms\Atari 2600\Roms",".a26",'Atari 2600',0,1)
folder_check("E:\Games\Roms\Atari Lynx\Roms",".lnx",'Atari Lynx',0,1)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @CGritton the error was, that the python start from A1 to fill in all the checks again. but with the solution that quamrana give me is all ok now.

Is a script to make an excel with all my collection rom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return `x` from your function and use it in the next call:

```
def folder_check (folder, exten, console, width, x):
    for rom in os.listdir(folder):
        # other stuff elided
            x += 1
    return x

x = folder_check("E:\Games\Roms\Atari 2600\Roms",".a26",'Atari 2600',0,1)
folder_check("E:\Games\Roms\Atari Lynx\Roms",".lnx",'Atari Lynx',0,x)
```

And if you want to include `width` as well:

```
def folder_check (folder, exten, console, width, x):
    for rom in os.listdir(folder):
        # other stuff elided
            x += 1
    return width,x

width,x = folder_check("E:\Games\Roms\Atari 2600\Roms",".a26",'Atari 2600',0,1)
folder_check("E:\Games\Roms\Atari Lynx\Roms",".lnx",'Atari Lynx',width,x)
```

Comment: thanks, and if i want to take 2 variables like x and width?